# Bulkloader CSV size error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

Bulkloader raises the following error when importing a CSV file with large cells:

```
[ERROR   ] Error in data source thread: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

This is a common problem for the csv module, which can be fixed with:

```
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxint)
```

How can I make bulkloader execute this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

In bulkloader.yaml add:

```
python_preamble:
- import: csv_fix
... # the rest of your imports
```

In csv_fix.py add:

```
import csv, sys
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxint)
```

Comment: Thank you! I really thought there was a bug in the CSV lib.